# Can a SPD workflow set variable to current item's latest approved version value?

Tags: designer-workflow, versioning, content-approval

We have a reusable workflow created with SharePoint designer. We are using SP2010 workflow engine. The workflow will be used on a list which content approval is enabled.

We have a problem on "set workflow variable" action. The action always get the latest version values from the list, regardless it is an approved or pending or rejected version.

We want to get the "Approved" version value only. Is it possible? Any workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but you can try the `Is current version`.

Make a `if` statement on the current item, look for: field is current version which is boolean and set it to `True`, in the if you can set your values:

```
If Current Item:Is Current Version equals value
{
   Set Variable: currentValue to Current Item:Field
}
```